# Cocos2d-x v3.2 CCSet Alternative after Deprecation C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In version 3.2 of Cocos2d-X CCSet is deprecated but I can't find an alternative to use with Ref* objects. I understand that I could use std::set for a basic set data structure but that I would have to do my own memory management. Looking at the old CCSet, I don't really see anything wrong with it.

My questions are:

How should we be handling sets of Ref* objects in Cocos2d-x now that CCSet is deprecated?

If we are to just use std::set, what should that look like to ensure we release and retain objects added to the set correctly; and how does that differ from how the current CCSet does it - in other words, why not just use the deprecated CCSet class?

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2d-X versions >3.0 you can use __Set class.